# New Note button doesn't properly set retURL for VF pages?

Tags: contentnote

We are not using Lightning, but recently transitioned to using the new 'enhanced note-taking tool'.

We use a VF page for our Opportunity object, and have the new Notes related list on our page:

```
<apex:relatedList list="AttachedContentNotes" subject="{!opp}"/>
```

When I click the standard 'New Note' button from this page, however, this is the URL for the note page (emphasis mine):

> https://na29.salesforce.com/06934000001xv4A?**retUrl=%2Fapex%2Fopportunitybyproducts**&parentId=00634000013LYpj

This retURL causes an error when hitting the 'Cancel' button on the Note page, because you can't just return to a VF page without a record ID parameter.

Clicking into an *existing* note provides a working retURL, however:

> https://na29.salesforce.com/06934000001xv5h?parentId=00634000013LYpj&**retUrl=/00634000013LYpj**

I believe the fix is to change retURL to '/{oppID}', but I'm not sure how to do that without building an entirely new visualforce component to replace the Notes related list. Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found the known issue, copy pasted below:** https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000jkoaQAA

> Cancel button on Visualforce Page having Enhanced Notes related List
>   does not respect returnURL
>
> Apex , Spring 16 , Summer 15 , Summer 16 , Winter 16
>
> Last updated 12 days ago ·Reference W-2826983 ·Reported By 4 users IN
>   REVIEW
>
> Summary When a Related List is created on a VF Page for Notes records,
>   using , it contains
>   "Save" and "Cancel" buttons which are displayed after we click on "New
>   Note" button to create a Note record.
>
> When the "Cancel" button is clicked, the User is redirected to the VF
>   page, but the URL does not contain the ID of the record in the URL.
>
> So, if the URL when the VF Page was loaded was
>   https://.salesforce.com/apex/myVFPage?id=
>
> and the "Cancel" button is clicked, the User is redirected to :
>
> https://.salesforce.com/apex/myVFPage
>
> The same thing happens when you click on "Save" button and then
>   "Cancel" button, the Note record gets saved but the redirection works
>   in the same way mentioned above.
>
> Repro In any Org :
>
> - Enable "Enhanced Notes" feature : https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Consideration-for-enhanced-notes-and-using-Files&language=en_US
> - Create a VF page with name is "MyVfPage" the following code :
>
> - Get the ID of any Account record and go to this URL :
>
> https://.salesforce.com/apex/MyVfPage?id=
>
> - Now click on "New Notes".
> - On the screen which has opened, click on "Cancel" (Or You can click on "Save" and then "Cancel").
> - You will notice that the User is redirected to the VF page, but the URL does not contain the ID :
>     https://.salesforce.com/apex/MyVfPage
>
> Workaround Use "Back" button of browser to go to the previous page.